# Как запустить скрипт Python на другом PC

Tags: python

Здравствуйте, начал изучать Python. 
Задался вопросом, как запустить скрипт на другом компьютере (оба PC на Windows), не подготавливая машину (не устанавливая Python)? 
Все, что смог найти, - это способ формирования .exe файла при помощи py2exe.

Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли альтернативные пути распространения скрипта (более "правильные") и какие минусы у этого подхода.

В книжке нет (возможно, еще не дочитал) способов, описывающих перенос, может, я просто еще не понимаю назначение этого языка?

Python может сильно помочь, если нужно что-то автоматизировать, работая на "моем" компьютере. Или web-приложения, которые также не требуют предустановки Python на компьютер конечного пользователя.
Так же я понял:
Но еще на нем можно написать обычную десктопную программу, оптимизируя критические места на C++. 
Но зачем писать десктопные программы, если их нельзя отдать конечному пользователю? Или обычно в таких случая в установщик добавляют еще и установщик Python?

Буду особенно признателен за ответ в виде ссылки на статью (или полноценный ресурс), которая поможет мне разобраться в том, как используют Python в реальной разработке.

Comment: Из не игрушек, [Dropbox (100M+ пользователей) создавала свой клиент на Windows с помощью py2exe](https://github.com/kholia/dedrop)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это проблема Windows. В Linux этой проблемы нет - на этих операционных системах он обычно уже есть "из коробки" (например, в Fedora много скриптов на нем написано).

Правильный способ - это сделать два инсталлятора программы: один - со встроенным Python, второй - без.

Тот инсталлятор, который со встроенным Python должен иметь либо полный инсталлятор Python и устанавливать ее нормально (но при этом должен быть готовым, что Python уже будет у пользователя), либо содержать минимально необходимую версию Python и держать у себе в папке.

Я бы сделал следующее: инсталлятор без Python с возможностью скачивания его из Интернета, если он не установлен у пользователя.